# I am trying to get user email from firebase, But typescript giving this error in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am trying to get user email from firebase the when the user will login. That's why I can't define user before. I used optional chaining but react typescript giving error
[image: react typescript error]

[image: Code]

Comment: Has nothing to do with optional chaining, the property "email" does not exist on the user variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need just add 'Email' to type of UserCredential

Comment: can you please tell me how can i do that?

Comment: if you will give information where and how get "user", sure.

Comment: thanks bro i just figured it out.